# the simplest test to check ODP connectivity

Tags: oracle, database-connection, odp.net

I want to install a new version of ODP into a production environment and I'm looking for the simplest test that the drivers have actually gone on ok, and the bespoke apps on the server can still connect to the database.

Sounds easy, but there are some caveats...

First, one thing I need to do over-and-above the Oracle setup is to manually introduce a key into the registry, TNS_ADMIN. This is critical to the environment I'm installing to and when this key is missing, or the path is incorrect, this is the normal cause of problems. Effectively, this is what I'm actually looking to test.

Next, since these are production servers, there are no tools installed on them, so I can't just run up a copy of Toad, for example. The only truly safe assumption for the software present will be the operating system (Windows 2003) and the Oracle drivers (ODP 11.2 R3 which at the time of writing is Oracle's current production version).

Next, the bespoke apps on there are generally service-oriented, so simply saying "just run up one of the apps" might be easier said than done. Also on this point, it won't actually be me whose running these drivers in, but will be an operator who will have limited knowledge of what they're doing (sad but true). So whatever test I settle on, its got to be easy enough for the guy to follow, and easy enough for him to interpret the results.

Next, I'm fully aware I could write a 5-line test rig just to open and close a connection. This has the advantage of making life easy for the operator, and is definitely a fallback option, but can't help wondering if there is an easier approach.

I guess I'm just wondering whether anyone knows of some kind of utility, which more than likely ships with ODP, which will effect a connection test. Even if I end up giving the operator a .bat file to execute it'll be simpler (and less error prone???) than writing my own app.

Points for the best suggestion,
Pete

Comment: I'll put this in a comment just in case someone comes up with an even better way to do it, but I think I have the answer. I can get the operator to create an ODBC connection and to test it. I can do this just using Windows, no additional software required, they just need to make sure they use the right driver and have a valid database login to hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the operator to create an ODBC connection and to test it. I can do this just using Windows, no additional software required, they just need to make sure they use the right driver and have a valid database login to hand

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is one in just ODP.net, no. At least, I don't see anything in the Entity Framework beta version of it (which I have installed).

In the larger driver packages you could use SQL*Plus, which is a command line tool. But for your purposes the simplest answer is likely to write a very small app that just connects and does a `SELECT * FROM DUAL;`

Comment: hi Tridus, yeah, in our development environments we install the version of the drivers that is tooled-up for Visual Studio and which probably comes with all sorts of diagnostic stuff (which I don't need because I have SQL Navigator). But in test and production environments we go minimal...